What is the proper way to replace a pallet with an entirely new one in a runtime migration?
We have pallet_xyz and we want to replace it with pallet_abc at the exact same pallet index, i.e. just removing one and replacing the other. What's the proper way to migrate this?
More specifically, we start with
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime
    {
        System: frame_system,
        XYZ: pallet_xyz,
    }
);

And we move to:
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime
    {
        System: frame_system,
        ABC: pallet_abc,
    }
);

Is it possible to do this safely or should we never use that pallet index again if we delete it?


Eliminate the old pallet and its storage, ensuring these items are no longer in use.
Introduce the new pallet.

If you are confident that the call index is not utilized elsewhere, feel free to retain the same call index.
If there is any uncertainty, select a new index for the new pallet. You can safely discard the old index in the upcoming runtime upgrades to make the index available for other pallets in later, as it has been unused since the last runtime upgrade.
On the infrastructure side, you should always instruct them to avoid hardcoding that index, as the call is no longer available.
